# Can I have a linked text box over a larger linked image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, hyperlink

I have a lot of photos with links to wherever, and I'd like to have a semi-transparent box come up on hover, after a delay, with caption and copyright for the larger underlying photo. In my dreams, I'd like the smaller overlay to link to the original photo or the photographer's site, while the still-visible area of the underlying image will still link to wherever. If it make a difference, this is on a Joomla site (with jQuery already loaded) but I'm generally able to hack the PHP and HTML on the template.

I see a few pretty straightforward ways to overlay a linked box over a non-linked image or a non-linked box over a linked image, but can I set up a linked box over a larger linked image, with the overlying box intercepting clicks just on itself? I'm guessing that this would require some JavaScript, but at this point I only have a hazy understanding of JavaScript, so at very least I need to know whether JavaScript can ultimately do that, before I get into this, and I'd love to get a generic script to do this.

The overlying box can be in a consistent location -- like full-width at the bottom of the underlying image -- rather than, say, a tooltip located relative to the mouse cursor. Seems like a script would have to respond to a click in the image area, then check whether it also falls inside the overlying box, and act accordingly. Could a script do that, and, um, might I get a rough scrip for something like that?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net to see what problem you are having with your code?

Comment: The initial problem is that I don't have any code, nor do I know exactly where to start. I'm sure I can get moderately up to speed if I focus some energy into it, but I don't want to dive into the deep end of JavaScript right at the moment if it can't ultimately do what I'm asking it to do. It's kind of a 2-part question:

1. Can JavaScript be made to do this?

2. If so, could I get even the roughest outline of such a script?